# How to use postgres numeric range with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I can't happen to find much on using [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) range types in SQLAlchemy other than [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ranges.RangeOperators). Does anyone know how to insert new column values into a numrange column? Does anyone have some code snippets or more documentation than the one I already found?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been added to the official documentation: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3046/postgresql-range-types-need-better

---

Had to dig around for this, but when in doubt, check the tests!  The [SQLAlchemy tests for the range types](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/55eacc8dbea3c3f98197bde9034fd6558fb2bc09/test/dialect/postgresql/test_types.py?at=master#cl-1589) use the underlying [psycopg2 types](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#range-data-types).

```
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INT4RANGE
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql:///example', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    window = Column(INT4RANGE, nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all()

session.add(Example(window=NumericRange(2, 6)))
session.add(Example(window=NumericRange(4, 8)))
session.commit()
```